# Do distributed compilers need dependencies when compiling something?

Tags: compilation, linker, distributed

Considering a distributed compiler such as incredibuild or distcc, suppose I send a compile job to a remote machine to compile a C++ source file that depends on a static or dynamic library (something that I would need to install in order to build my program). Does the remote machine need that library in order to compile it?

From my understanding of C and C++, when a source file is compiled into an object file, the compiler "stubs" out anything external to the source code (such as a call to a function that is not in the code, i.e. only defined as part of a header). When the linking occurs, that's when the dependencies need to be present so the linker can inspect them figure out where a function is implemented. If that is the case, does this mean, distributed compilers can only do compile+link if they have the dependencies installed? Does the same hold true for both dynamic and static libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The build order is indeed the heart of any successful compilation process :) Distributed builds must obtain the same build order while performing the build in a much more parallel manner.
When you perform a build with IncrediBUild, the machine that starts the build, is managing the build process and making sure that each distributed compilation task will be built in the correct build order no matter which machine actually performs the build. When a compilation task is sent to a remote machine, it is sent along with the base environment settings of the machine that started the build. We call it "Process Virtualization".
If during the compilation of that remote process, a certain file is needed (like in a scenario you have described) IncrediBuild can fetch it from the machine that started the build and place it in the cache of the remote machine. This file will be used for this compilation task and will be kept in the cache of the remote machine for future use.
Because of this mechanism, the remote machines doesnt need to have any source files at all. They can basically be regular Windows machines - without any development environment. 
Hope I was able to shed some light on this issue.

Comment: Somewhat, yes :) But my question was more specific to the requirements of compiling vs linking. Does the process of compiling source code to an object file require the libraries? Or is that only required when linking?